# Wheel heading using PWM

Tags: pwm, signal, reference

I have a general question which im not sure how to implement.

Suppose that a car is driving on a straight road and it starts doing some maneuver.

Due to this maneuver the driver moves the wheel left and right in some not uniform "wave" like this:

[image]

For Example at the beginning he moves the wheel to the right for about maximum 2 degrees then left for about 1 degree and so on.

Once he finished his drive, I take the information from the car and I have a dataset of the movments of the wheel (Basically a matrix that its first column is time and the second column is the angle of the wheel).

Now, I had like to take this data and to make an equivalent PWM that will eventually move the wheel at the same manner as it did before once I inject this data to the actuator.

Is there a way to implement a PWM signal that will represent the "wave"?

Im asking because from what I know the reference signal here is not in constant frequency and im not sure how it is possible to recreate a PWM signal in that way.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'deal with it'?

Comment: info: most hobby servos use PWM for positioning the actuator ..... https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hobby-servo-tutorial

Comment: what does this mean ?  ... `the reference signal here`

Comment: You mean like a class D amplifier?

Comment: I read about this amplifier but it still seems like I need to give it the PWM, my question is how do I know what pulses to give? I dont have here some constant frequency signa

Comment: I read about this amplifier but it still seems like I need to give it the PWM, my question is how do I know what pulses to give? I dont have here some constant frequency signal. In all of the xases I see the signal should be periodical with 2pi which is not what I have here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can easily be done. Lets assume the steering inputs are a MUCH lower "frequency" than the PWM frequency.

The pulse width effectively becomes an instantaneous signal, like a voltage. Now you've just got to map the signal to the wheel position. The pulse width can't be negative, so you should introduce an offset to give yourself some space.

Older RC equipment does exactly this. They map a pulse width of 1500uS to 0%, 1000us to -100% and 2000uS to +100%.

Your "wave" will not get transmitted as a frequency. Rather it will be transmitted as a series of unique values (like graph points) that can be used to construct the original wave.